# Is it possible do display (.ico) files as thumbnails in Thunar file manager?

Tags: icons, xubuntu, thumbnails, thunar

Thunar displays thumbnails (almost) normally for image files, but for (*.ico) files only display a standard thumbnail. Is there some setting or plugin to solve this issue ? Or should I convert ico files to png files to display correctly ? Thanks, Vladi
PS: OS Xubuntu 16.0.5 / Thunar 1.6

Answer (score 1):

Icon files (.ico) are shown on my Xubuntu 18.04 with Thunar 1.6.15. My guess is, that either there was a bug in older Thunar versions, or that your icon files are corrupted in any way. I use Pinta to create icon files; it can reliably convert image files to other formats.